# How do I get my iPhone 8 to fast charge?

Tags: iphone, charging

I have an iPhone 8 and so far it’s been great, except for one thing. I was sure that the iPhone 8 supported fast charging, like up to 80% or something. but I barely notice much difference in terms of how quick it gets a charge compared to my iPhone 6s. I’ve checked Settings/Battery and tried Low Power Mode when on charge but that made no difference either. I looked elsewhere in Settings but didn’t see anything I can change to make it fast charge. So now I question myself and wonder:

- Was I wrong about the whole fast charging thing?
- Is it only the iPhone 8 Plus and iPhone X, or maybe just the iPhone X that supports fast charging?
- Or is there just something I have to do to get it to fast charge?

Your assistance would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all of this year's newly released iPhones (8, 8 Plus and X) support fast charging. And no, there’s no *setting* you need to enable for it to work.

And, just to clarify, by fast charging you can recharge your iPhone up to 50% (not 80%) within the first 30 minutes.

However, for fast charging to work you need to use a charger that provides enough power for it to fast charge, and the chargers bundled with your iPhone only deliver 5 watts of power at up to 1 amp. By way of example, an iPad charger delivers 12 watts of power at up to 2.1 amps. **Note:** I am not saying that an iPad charger will *fast charge* your iPhone 8, although it would certainly charge it quicker than the standard iPhone charger.

Instead, I refer to what Apple says you need for fast charging your iPhone:

> Fast charging gives you a quick and convenient way to recharge your
>   iPhone 8 or iPhone 8 Plus. Your iPhone fast charges up to 50 percent
>   in 30 minutes when you use an Apple USB-C to Lightning cable and one
>   of these adapters:
>
> - Apple 29W, 61W, or 87W USB-C Power Adapter
> - A comparable third-party USB-C power adapter that supports USB Power Delivery (USB-PD)

For more info refer to: [Fast charge your iPhone 8 or iPhone 8 Plus](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT208137).

Comment: [iMore](https://www.imore.com/best-fast-and-cheap-usb-c-iphone-8-iphone-x-chargers) has some nice third-party recommendations for fast charging, if you're not a fan of Apple's prices.

Answer (score 0):

With a fast charger, you charge your Apple iPad/iPhone faster ( USB-C 18 W chargers minimum) than with a regular charger. The following models have the fast charging functionality:

- iPad Pro 12.9 inches (2015 or newer)
- iPad Pro 10.5 inches (2017)
- iPad Pro 11 inches (2018 and 2020)
- iPad Mini (2019)
- iPad Air (2019)

Fast charging is enabled with USB-C Power delivery standard and uses power profiles which can be selected dynamically during charging:

- 10W (5V, 2A)
- 18W (12V, 1.5A)
- 36W (12V, 3A)
- 60W (12V, 5A)
- 60W (20V, 3A)
- and 100W (20V, 5A)

The default profile is the 5V profile which makes the USB-C standard compatible with older devices (game controllers, iPhones, iPads, cameras etc.)
The logic behind switching between power profiles lays on a device which in  case of iPhone 8 and higher is:

- first 50% charge level is achieved with 18W profile
- next 50% of charge with 10 W profile (last 20% is charged with 5V/1A or less 5V/0.5A)

In USB-C Power Delivery standard a device being charged can communicate to  the charger informations about a device temperature which can be used as well by the charger to decrease allowed current or switch power profiles to lower for example.